# Relation between weight spaces of fixed loci of Hamiltonian $S^1$-actions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, group-actions

Consider an almost Kähler manifold $(M,\omega,I)$ with a $I$-(pseudo)holomorphic $\mathbb{C}^*$-action, whose $S^1$-part is Hamiltonian and the fixed locus
$F=M^{S^1}$ is compact. Then, it breaks $F=\sqcup_{i=1}^n F_i$ into a finite number of compact submanifolds $F_i,$ on each of which we have a uniform weight decomposition
$$p\in F_i, \ \ \ T_p M = \oplus H_i^j,$$ where $H_i^j$ is the $j$-weight space with respected to the induced $S^1$-action on $T_p.$

**Now the question:** Having a $\mathbb{C}^*$-orbit (or the gradient flowline of the moment map) that connects two different $F_{i_1},F_{i_2},$ what are the relations between their corresponding weight space decompositions?

The only obvious ones I can think of are:

1. The $\mathbb{C}*$-orbit starting from $H_{i_1}^j$, will end up in $H_{i_2}^{-j}$ (as the compactified $\mathbb{C}P^1$ has constant stabiliser of $S^1,$ and sign changes at the ends, from outwards to inwards).
2. Modulo-$j$, the weight decompositions should be the same, as $F_1$ and $F_2$ belong to the same connected component of $\mathbb{Z}/j$-action
   (Following the notation from 1)).

The question is whether there are there any more relations, in general?